# VIM: Moving to next sentence/paragraph without adding to navigation history

Tags: vim, gvim

I like to use the CTRL-O and CTRL-I keys to move around.  The problem is that it quickly fills up with small movements like moving by paragraph with }/{ or moving by sentence with )/( .  Is there a way to not have those keys affect the navigation history?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To avoid changes to the jump list, `:keepjumps` can be used. You have to overload any movement command with a mapping, like this:

```
:nnoremap <silent> } :<C-u>execute 'keepjumps normal!' v:count1 . '}'<CR>
```